PS Camera taking too much light on OpenCV
I installed a third-party driver and firmware to use my PS 4 Camera on PC and I need it to do a object detection project. Everything works fine on camera on Windows (the screen resolution looks buggy but this is simply how Windows read Sony data format).
Here is how it looks (I have a red light in the room):

--
When I open the same cam on OpenCV the image was looking very bright, or it looks very low quality.
Here is how the image looks in OpenCV when saved with imwrite():

In the first image you can clearly read ALIENWARE under the monitor, in the second image is clearly granulated.
I wrote the simplest code just to read and show the cam:
import cv2

#read

webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#visualize

while True:

    ret, frame = webcam.read()

    cv2.imshow('webcam', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(40) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

webcam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

How can I fix this?

You didn't show your code...

@MarkSetchell edited now

I don't use Windows or PS4, but if the camera is at all similar to the one on Raspberry Pi, it will have a "stills" mode for single-shot pictures and a "video" shooting mode for moving (video) pictures which acquires at a lower resolution with a lot less processing in order to achieve a higher video frame rate (fps). Using OpenCV  VideoCapture to read the image will then most likely select the lower quality video mode. I suspect you need to find out from the driver author how to read in "stills" mode. Maybe.

@MarkSetchell isn’t there a way to select that in OpenCV for how much you know?

You can use webcam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE,value) it takes negative values try -6 and fine tune to your needs. You can also set the video resolution, by default it opens as 640x480 i think. Try: webcam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,value) and webcam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,value) . Also check: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704d

do not screenshot. we need to see the frames 1:1. store them directly.

@ChristophRackwitz I don’t understand what you mean… I took a photo with the Windows camera app

@ChristophRackwitz was suggesting you call cv2.imwrite('frame.jpg', frame) after your cv2.waitKey() so that your app writes the file directly to disk itself rather than using screengrabbing.

@MarkSetchell I added the actual frame in my main question

at the end, there's a link. that looks like the actual image. the screenshot above it is now obsolete. I've just replaced the screenshot with the linked image. we now have 1:1 scale pictures. -- looks like the frame format is "strange". might be some kind of image pyramid. -- as for the image size... this should be addressed with a set() call of CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH and HEIGHT. that should work.

@ChristophRackwitz I tried that as Barış Aktaş was suggesting but nothing seems to change (visually and even when printing the value with get() ). Cam problem?

prototype with ffmpeg/ffplay instead. that gives you better control over the system API for camera devices

@ChristophRackwitz could you be more specific please?

you can and should post your own answer as an answer. it'll help people in the future find your solution.

I solved the problem! With ffmpeg/ffplay I figured out that this cam can only support certain frame/resolution combinations:
[dshow @ 000002e52f473900]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=3448x808 fps=8 max s=3448x808 fps=60.0002 (tv, bt470bg/bt709/unknown, topleft)
[dshow @ 000002e52f473900]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=1748x408 fps=8 max s=1748x408 fps=120 (tv, bt470bg/bt709/unknown, topleft)
[dshow @ 000002e52f473900]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=898x200 fps=30 max s=898x200 fps=240.004 (tv, bt470bg/bt709/unknown, topleft)

it appears that if you try to lower/increase the fps while keeping the same resolution it adjust the resolution itself to the nearest supported resolution but keeping the said framerate (if between min-max interval). That happens on OpenCV as well.
Now, with
    width = 3448  
    height = 808 
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)

    fps = 60
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, fps)

it outputs this image:
much better image
Thank you all for your help!

Firstly, try running on console:
v4l2-ctl -l

Then, you can increase or decrease.
v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl=contrast=6 # change, increasing or decreasing

